# What is lib.dynamiccontent

Tags: typo3, fluid

I try to untderstand the bootstrap_package for typo3 and in the fluid templates I don't find the output from styles.content.get i.e. Furthermore there is always used in the templates:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{pageUid: '{data.uid}', colPos: '0'}"/>
```

Is that the modern way to output content from the database instead of using `styles.content.get`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

lib.dynamicContent will be indeed a typoscript snippet that is used to place 'dynamic' content to a page and can be found at :

```
typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Configuration/TypoScript/Helper/DynamicContent.txt
```

The cObject that is called by fluid also uses 2 arguments: pageUid and colPos. These are send to the register of the lib.dynamicContent COA and used at the CONTENT part at `where = colPos={register:colPos}` and `pidInList.data = register:pageUid`

This is not really a 'modern' way of pulling the right content element at a page. If you look at css_styled_content, `styles.content.get` is just another constant that is loaded with a `CONTENT` object :

```
# Clear out any constants in this reserved room!
styles.content >

# get content
styles.content.get = CONTENT
styles.content.get {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.where = colPos=0
}

# get content, left
styles.content.getLeft < styles.content.get
styles.content.getLeft.select.where = colPos=1
```

You could create your own constant with a new name yourself, for example:

```
styles.content.getMyContent < styles.content.get
styles.content.getMyContent.select.where = colPos=999
```

The modern approach from the bootstrap_package is that the elements are rendered with FLUID. What will give you a much more flexible way to create your own templates.